# Bring simulator to front on run

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

After one of the more recent updates to Xcode or OS X, my iOS simulator is no longer brought to the front when I run my project. It used to automatically move to front and it was super convenient. Anyone know if this is something I can re-enable?

Answer (score 5):

I have same issue, I tried **Simulator-->Window-->Bring All to Front** and issues is solved.

Comment: Since posting, the issue resolved itself for me but it may show up again. Once you do that a single time will it present in front the next time you run or just for that specific run?

Comment: On every app run via Xcode, now my simulator come to front automatically (after trying the posted solution once). But simulator won't come to front when I run the XCTest UI testing test-case. I need to figure out how to fix this test-case issue.